# OS X El Capitan - Running Mavericks off of usb drive

Tags: macos

So I plan to erase my MacBook Pro completely. After I erase its drive from an El Capitan recovery drive that I have, I want to boot into Internet recovery mode, plug in another flashdrive, install Mavericks on it, and then use the recovery drive for El Capitan to install El Capitan onto my MacBooks internal SSD.

Basically, I want to have El Capitan on my internal SSD and Mavericks on my external USB drive. Is this possible at all, to have an older version of OS X installed on an external device?

Comment: So you have El Capitan or Mavericks on your Macbook at the moment? If it has Mavericks, are you willing to clone it onto external drive or must it be clean install.

Comment: As of right now, it is running 10.11.5. I can access the Internet recovery partition which is Mavericks. And yes it should be a clean install

Comment: You have the .app file for Mavericks? And do you have an extra usb drive to load the mavericks installation on it?

Comment: I do have a Mavericks installer BUT it does not work with specifically my model (Prohibited sign on boot). However, I do have the time to install of from Internet recovery mode which has worked before. I can boot into Internet recovery and install on the USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Mavericks install app:

1. Copy the `Install OS X Mavericks.app` file to your desktop
2. Insert the flash drive you want the installation files to be copied to
3. Download this [script](https://gist.github.com/emotality/2e73dbdce953b094c755af06449a3d08), unzip it, then move the `osx_10.9_bootable.sh` file to your Desktop.
4. Open Terminal app, then type `cd ~/Desktop/` and hit enter
5. Then type `sh osx_10.9_bootable.sh` and follow instructions then wait

If this was successful, restart your Mac and hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key then select the newly created installation drive to install Mavericks onto your external HDD.

[image: Pick USB drive]
[image: Select external drive to install OSX]
*(in this case, 0553225513 is my external hdd, which will be your flash drive)*

After the installation you can [reinstall OS X El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT204904) on your Macbook.

Comment: The .app installer that i have does not support my MacBook Pro

Comment: Well you dont have to install, the script will make a bootable drive out of it. Just do the steps?

Comment: I don't have access to my Mac for 2 weeks, but I have tried using my installer to make a bootable drive in the past. It has a prohibited sign when I try to boot from the flashdrive.

Comment: So you wanna install it to your mac but you dont have access to it? lol dafuq?

Comment: Lol I wanna install it when I do get it back (repairs and I'm away), I thought I'd ask my question beforehand so I would have an answer before I got back to it

Comment: Lol okay well I'm busy downloading Mavericks to do these steps myself. Will let you know if it works. :)

Comment: What Mac do you have? The installer that I have is 10.9.0, which was released before my computer and doesn't work

Comment: Updated with images that shows it's working on El Capitan! :)